# How to build samsung S22u kernel?

Tags: samsung-mobile

First of all, I download the source code from the Samsung open source website(SM-S908U_NA_13_Opensource.zip).

Then download the cross-compilation tool chain and extract it to the corresponding folder

However, this error occurs when I run the compilation script：

```
or/cam_actuator_core.c:1636:9: error: redefinition of 'cam_actuator_i2c_read'
int32_t cam_actuator_i2c_read(struct cam_actuator_ctrl_t *a_ctrl, uint32_t addr,
        ^
/home/ulis/kernel13/kernel_platform/msm-kernel/../../vendor/qcom/opensource/camera-kernel/drivers/cam_sensor_module/cam_actuator/cam_actuator_core.c:149:9: note: previous definition is here
int32_t cam_actuator_i2c_read(struct cam_actuator_ctrl_t *a_ctrl, uint32_t addr,
        ^
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [/home/ulis/kernel13/kernel_platform/msm-kernel/scripts/Makefile.build:278：../../vendor/qcom/opensource/camera-kernel/drivers/cam_sensor_module/cam_actuator/cam_actuator_core.o] 错误 1
make[3]: *** 正在等待未完成的任务....
make[2]: *** [/home/ulis/kernel13/kernel_platform/msm-kernel/Makefile:1940：../../vendor/qcom/opensource/camera-kernel] 错误 2
make[2]: 离开目录“/home/ulis/kernel13/out/msm---gki/msm-kernel”
make[1]: *** [Makefile:189: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ulis/kernel13/kernel_platform/msm-kernel'
make: *** [Makefile:10: modules] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/ulis/kernel13/vendor/qcom/opensource/camera-kernel'
```

I want to know how to compile the kernel code of Samsung successfully.

Solve the above problems

Comment: Can you provide further information about what you already tried to solve the problem yourself? Stackoverflow isn't a place where you tell people to solve your problems. Your last sentence indicates that this is exactly what you want. Stackoverflow is a place where you ask specific questions, tell us what you already tried etc.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't describe it clearly. First, I downloaded the kernel source code of s22u from the Samsung open source website and compiled the kernel according to the file description_ The code file in the platform folder encountered some errors that could not be found. I just want to ask if there is any code file that has the same experience as me.